# How to reproduce examples from ShaderToy on my computer?

Tags: opengl, rendering, glsl

I am a beginner with computer graphics. I have some experience with drawing polygons, shaded surfaces, the use of geometry shaders, etc. I am trying to create a volumetric cloud/volume render shader like [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlBSRz), with techniques such as 'raymarching'. The problem is that I have understood that graphics are rendered throughout a pipeline (generate vertex information with cpu, store them in buffer objects, process them with the vertex shader and then render the image with the fragment shaders), so for me it is not clear at what stage of the pipeline the volumetric rendering is done, since the cloud is not made of polygons or vertex in general. My first step would be reproducing the same rendering from shadertoy, to understand the technique better, add parameters, lighting, etc. What kind of shader is it? how should I write a program to use it? I use OpenGL in Linux. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [Shadertoy documentation](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto) to find the answer to your question? It explicitly states that the `mainImage` entrypoint is called per pixel — ie. it's a pixel shader (AKA fragment shader). What have you tried so far in your quest to render a shader in your program, and where specifically are you stuck? Rendering a quad with a custom shader is something that just about every OpenGL tutorial covers, so it seems like you should find answers to most of your questions out there already in existing documents, without waiting for new answers here.

Comment: What I understand is that I should make a rectangle with just 2 triangles next to each other, from re-reading OpenGL tutorials, right?. That was what I thought first, but I got confused because in that website there is just one shader, and I imagined that you could then compile a shader with just the fragment shader alone. Answering where I was stuck: At the beginning, I did not know how to write the vertex/fragment shaders and how to link and compile, since I did not understand the rendering pipeline in these case. Thank you for your time

Comment: Shadertoy handles the vertex shader itself, that's why you don't have to write one. Can you edit your question to show us what you've tried so far and where exactly you're stuck?